# Type Casting Issues After upgrading to Angular 4

Tags: angular, jhipster, angular2-services

After upgrading to Angular 4 I am getting below error
[enter image description here][1]

client?afea:119 [at-loader] ./src/test/javascript/spec/app/account/settings/settings.component.spec.ts:49:13 
    TS2322: Type 'Principal' is not assignable to type 'MockPrincipal'.
  Property 'identitySpy' is missing in type 'Principal'.

[at-loader] ./src/test/javascript/spec/app/account/settings/settings.component.spec.ts:48:13 
    TS2322: Type 'AccountService' is not assignable to type 'MockAccountService'.
  Property 'getSpy' is missing in type 'AccountService'.

**settings.component.spec.ts**

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { JhiLanguageHelper } from '../../../../../../main/webapp/app/shared';
import { AgreeGatewayTestModule } from '../../../test.module';
import { Principal, AccountService } from '../../../../../../main/webapp/app/shared';
import { SettingsComponent } from '../../../../../../main/webapp/app/account/settings/settings.component';
import { MockAccountService } from '../../../helpers/mock-account.service';
import { MockPrincipal } from '../../../helpers/mock-principal.service';


describe('Component Tests', () => {

    describe('SettingsComponent', () => {

        let comp: SettingsComponent;
        let fixture: ComponentFixture<SettingsComponent>;
        let mockAuth: MockAccountService;
        let mockPrincipal: MockPrincipal;

        beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                imports: [AgreeGatewayTestModule],
                declarations: [SettingsComponent],
                providers: [
                    {
                        provide: Principal,
                        useClass: MockPrincipal
                    },
                    {
                        provide: AccountService,
                        useClass: MockAccountService
                    },
                    {
                        provide: JhiLanguageHelper,
                        useValue: null
                    },
                ]
            }).overrideComponent(SettingsComponent, {
                set: {
                    template: ''
                }
            }).compileComponents();
        }));

        beforeEach(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SettingsComponent);
            comp = fixture.componentInstance;
            console.log(AccountService);
            mockAuth = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(AccountService);
            mockPrincipal = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Principal);
        });

        it('should send the current identity upon save', function () {
            // GIVEN
            let accountValues = {
                firstName: 'John',
                lastName: 'Doe',

                activated: true,
                email: 'john.doe@mail.com',
                langKey: 'en',
                login: 'john'
            };
            mockPrincipal.setResponse(accountValues);

            // WHEN
            comp.settingsAccount = accountValues;
            comp.save();

            // THEN
            expect(mockPrincipal.identitySpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(mockAuth.saveSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(accountValues);
            expect(comp.settingsAccount).toEqual(accountValues);
        });

        it('should notify of success upon successful save', function () {
            // GIVEN
            let accountValues = {
                firstName: 'John',
                lastName: 'Doe'
            };
            mockPrincipal.setResponse(accountValues);

            // WHEN
            comp.save();

            // THEN
            expect(comp.error).toBeNull();
            expect(comp.success).toBe('OK');
        });

        it('should notify of error upon failed save', function () {
            // GIVEN
            mockAuth.saveSpy.and.returnValue(Observable.throw('ERROR'));

            // WHEN
            comp.save();

            // THEN
            expect(comp.error).toEqual('ERROR');
            expect(comp.success).toBeNull();
        });
    });
});
```

**account.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class AccountService  {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    get(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('api/account').map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }

    save(account: any): Observable<Response> {
        return this.http.post('api/account', account);
    }
}
```

**mock-account.service.ts**

```
import { SpyObject } from './spyobject';
import { AccountService } from '../../../../main/webapp/app/shared/auth/account.service';
import Spy = jasmine.Spy;

export class MockAccountService extends SpyObject {

    getSpy: Spy;
    saveSpy: Spy;
    fakeResponse: any;

    constructor() {
        super(AccountService);

        this.fakeResponse = null;
        this.getSpy = this.spy('get').andReturn(this);
        this.saveSpy = this.spy('save').andReturn(this);
    }

    subscribe(callback: any) {
        callback(this.fakeResponse);
    }

    setResponse(json: any): void {
        this.fakeResponse = json;
    }
}
```

**mock-principal.service.ts**

```
import { SpyObject } from './spyobject';
import { Principal } from '../../../../main/webapp/app/shared/auth/principal.service';
import Spy = jasmine.Spy;

export class MockPrincipal extends SpyObject {

    identitySpy: Spy;
    fakeResponse: any;

    constructor() {
        super(Principal);

        this.fakeResponse = {};
        this.identitySpy = this.spy('identity').andReturn(Promise.resolve(this.fakeResponse));
    }

    setResponse(json: any): void {
        this.fakeResponse = json;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not so familiar with testing, so I really don't know, but have you extended your mock classes?
like: `class MockPrincipal extends Principal {}` Could you provide one of your mock classes as well?

Comment: If you use `SpyObject` as the super class in your mocks, then you must provide that service in your testbed. `providers: [
                    {
                        provide: Principal,
                        useClass: SpyObject
                    }` (I think)

Comment: I have added in testModule providers array but no luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am not so familiar with testing, so I really don't know, but I think you have to provide the correct service in your testbed. You mocks need to extend the providers in order to not get a type conflict.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                imports: [AgreeGatewayTestModule],
                declarations: [SettingsComponent],
                providers: [
                    {
                        provide: SpyObject, //changed this
                        useClass: MockPrincipal
                    },
                    {
                        provide: SpyObject, //changed this
                        useClass: MockAccountService
                    },
                    {
                        provide: JhiLanguageHelper,
                        useValue: null
                    },
                ]
            }).overrideComponent(SettingsComponent, {
                set: {
                    template: ''
                }
            }).compileComponents();
        }));
```

If that does ***not*** work, you could instead try to change the extension of your mock objects with `Principal` and `AccountService`

```
export class MockPrincipal extends Principal {

    identitySpy: Spy;
    fakeResponse: any;

    constructor() {
        super(Principal);

        this.fakeResponse = {};
        this.identitySpy = this.spy('identity').andReturn(Promise.resolve(this.fakeResponse));
    }

    setResponse(json: any): void {
        this.fakeResponse = json;
    }
}
```

and

```
export class MockAccountService extends AccountService {

    getSpy: Spy;
    saveSpy: Spy;
    fakeResponse: any;

    constructor() {
        super(AccountService);

        this.fakeResponse = null;
        this.getSpy = this.spy('get').andReturn(this);
        this.saveSpy = this.spy('save').andReturn(this);
    }

    subscribe(callback: any) {
        callback(this.fakeResponse);
    }

    setResponse(json: any): void {
        this.fakeResponse = json;
    }
}
```